# Is there any way to generate Client ID and Client Secret using rest api for google auto-ml?

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-automl

I'm able to authenticate the user using client id and client secret(taking from GCP console). But is there any way to generate this client id and secret using REST APIs or Java SDK by taking user-id and password as an input parameter?

Comment: No - there is no public API available.

Answer (score 0):

There is currently a [public feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/116182848) already made on this. The current headway appears to be that you can programmatically set the consent screen for an internal app and create a client ID of type web with this [API](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/reference/rest#rest-resource:-v1.projects.brands) and [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/programmatic-oauth-clients).

To authenticate you will first need to create a brand, which is essentially the OAuth consent screen. Note that a brand can be internal or public, but this API only allows the use of an **internal brand**.

To create a brand you can either call the [brands.create() API](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.brands/create) or use the [gcloud command](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/alpha/iap/oauth-brands/create).

```
POST https://iap.googleapis.com/v1p1alpha1/projects/[PROJECT_ID_OR_NUMBER]/brands


gcloud alpha iap oauth-brands create --application_title=APPLICATION_TITLE --support_email=SUPPORT_EMAIL
```

With the brand you can then create the client ID and secret:

```
POST https://iap.googleapis.com/v1/projects/[PROJECT_ID_OR_NUMBER]/brands/[BRAND_NAME]/identityAwareProxyClients
```

Comment: How can i authenticate to use this API?

Comment: Edited my answer to provide more details on how to use the API and the restrictions.

Comment: Yes, I've read about the internal and public brand on the documentation shared by you. But as of now, I'm trying to use this API using postman and I need to authenticate before using it. So is there any way to authenticate me just by using my username and password?